# How to get a specific row field using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm using `CodeIgniter` with `EasyAppointments` library for a scheduler activity. I'm not an expert of `CodeIgniter` and I want to know how I can get a specific row field with a query execution. I've already created the ajax request, the model as documentation describe but now I need help for do this. First of all this is the content that I pass to the function (that must execute the select query):

```
Response =>  array(4) {
  ["nome"]=>
  string(5) "Jack"
  ["cognome"]=>
  string(6) "Mustrend"
  ["email"]=>
  string(22) "jcsk@gmail.com"
  ["mobile"]=>
  string(0) "0000"
}
```

The variable above `$operatore_info` contains the details of my operatore available in the db table called `users`. The structure of the table is the following:

```
id
first_name
last_name
email
mobile_number
phone_number
address
city
state
zip_code
notes
id_roles
```

Now the query in `sql` should be like this:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE first_name = nome AND last_name = cognome AND email = email AND mobile_number = mobile
```

How you can see I want return only the id of the user, How I can achieve this?

**UPDATE POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

```
public function returnSpecificOperatorId($operatore_information)
{
    //I parametri passati contengono i dettagli dell'operatore a cui dobbiamo prelevare l'id
    $nome = $operatore_information['nome'];
    $cognome = $operatore_information['cognome'];
    $email = $operatore_information['email'];
    $mobile = $operatore_information['mobile'];

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('ea_users');
    $this->db->where(array(
        'first_name'    => $nome,
        'last_name'      => $cognome,
        'email' => $email,
        'mobile_number' => $mobile
    ));
    $res = $this->db->get('users');
    var_dump($res);
    return $res;
}
```

This code return me:

> POST http://localhost/Calendario/backend_api/ajax_getSpecOpId 500 (Internal Server Error)

where the ajax request was performed:

```
    var myObj = {};
    myObj.nome = nome;
    myObj.cognome = cognome;
    myObj.email = email;
    myObj.mobile = mobile;

    var postUrl  = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + 'backend_api/ajax_getSpecOpId';
    var postData = { 'operatore_data': myObj };


    $.post(postUrl, postData, function(response) 
    {
        console.log("Response => " , response);
    });
```

Comment: can you show how are you executing the query and getting this result ?

Comment: I've updated the question check

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE first_name = nome AND last_name = cognome AND email = email AND mobile_number = mobile");
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result);

if(empty($count) || $count >1)
{
    echo "Invalid User";
}
else
{
    $id = $result[0]['id'];
    echo "User Id is ".$id ;
}
```

Comment: use my code in your model and post your ajax part too

Comment: [look at this](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/simple-ajax-post-example-with-php-codeIgniter-framework-and-jquery)

Comment: with $.ajax the same problem... I've already used ajax in the past

Comment: Post that will debug that

Answer (score 0):

If you get 500 internal sever error in code you have most probably **Syntax problem** or **SQL query  problem**. please check it.

If you working with AJAX please check console to get all PHP ERORR in response.

Comment: the problem is in the returnSpecificOperatorId. How I can debug it?

Comment: You check it in console ?, if you use firbug in mozila firefox you can get actual error please write your error here so i will give you proper answer for that.

Comment: I've fixed check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, thanks to all that led me in the right direction. So, after the `where` clause we have to do this:

```
$res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

instead of this:

```
$res = $this->db->get('users');
```